# unauthorize 401 when trying to load table from server using Json can work if use ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, token

Hi i would like some help on authorize my token to json as if i use ajax where i store my api key under my storage it will work but in json due to there no storing in json so i not sure how to work

here the code for the script this dont work

```
<script>



  $.ajax({
  
    url:"https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get",

    method:"GET",
    // In this case, we are going to use headers as
    headers:{
      // The query you're planning to call
      // i.e. <query> can be UserGet(0), RecyclableGet(0), etc.
      query:"RecyclableGet(0)",
      
      // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
      apikey:sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
    },

    success:function(data,xhr,textStatus) {
      const buildTable = data => {
    const table = document.querySelector('.table tbody');

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let row = `<tr>
  <td>${data[i].RecyclableID}</td>
  <td>${data[i].Name}</td>
  <td>${data[i].RecyclableType}</td>
  </tr>`;
      table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', row);
    }
  };

  const getData = async(url) => {

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    return buildTable(json);
  };
   getData('https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get');



  $(document).ready(function() {
    const btns = $('.change-row');
    $("tbody").on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
      /* //Add this line if you want only a single row selected
  
      $('tbody tr').not($(this)).removeClass('highlight');
      */
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight');

      if ($('tbody tr').hasClass('highlight')) {
        btns.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled dark');
      } else {
        btns.prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled dark');
      }

    });
  });
  

    },

    error:function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

if use ajax code for authorize this works

```
$.ajax({
                            
                                url:"https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get",
                        
                                method:"GET",
                                // In this case, we are going to use headers as
                                headers:{
                                    // The query you're planning to call
                                    // i.e. <query> can be UserGet(0), RecyclableGet(0), etc.
                                    query:"RecyclableGet(0)",
                                    
                                    // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
                                    apikey:sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
                                },
                    
                                success:function(data,xhr,textStatus) {
                                
                                console.log(data);
                                
                                },

                                error:function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                            });
```

i try to store inside ajax to call but it don't work as is calling the json instead causing 401 does any know how fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have solve the solution by

```
const getData = async(url) => {

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        query:"RecyclableGet(0)",
      
      // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
      apikey:sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
  }
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    return buildTable(json);
  };
   getData('https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get');
```

For future notice if people wan to figure out